# Error centering text on CSS3 button

Tags: html, css, centering

I am trying to center the text "verksamheter" on my CSS3 button, but I can't get it to work.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="verksamheter"><span>Verksamheter</span></a>
```

CSS:

```
.verksamheter {
  width: 220px;
  height: 44px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;   
  -webkit-border-radius: 22px;
  -moz-border-radius: 22px;
  border-radius: 22px;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.13), inset 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.13), inset 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,.75);
  box-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.13), inset 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,.75);
  border: solid 1px #4f4d6a;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6e6c8a, #4f4d6a);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6e6c8a, #4f4d6a);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6e6c8a, #4f4d6a);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6e6c8a, #4f4d6a);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #6e6c8a, #4f4d6a);   
}

.verksamheter span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The height of the `<a>` is 44px, so make the `line-height` of the text `44px` as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/s4KJd/

Answer (score 2):

Simply set the `line-height` property according to the height of the element and the font size used. For example:

```
.verksamheter {
    line-height: 44px;
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9tKYf/).